# Unable to import TorchVision after installation Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

I've installed Pytorch and Torchvision in the way suggested on their website via pip within a virtual environment (env), and whilst no errors occur during installation when I go to import torchvision in my python code the following error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torchvision
  File "/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torchvision import datasets
  File "/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .fakedata import FakeData
  File "/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/fakedata.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import transforms
  File "/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .transforms import *
  File "/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import functional as F
  File "/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, PILLOW_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name 'PILLOW_VERSION' from 'PIL' (/Users/QuinceyBee/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

I have tried creating new virtual environments to rebuild from scratch, tried to install via conda within a conda environment, however, neither of these resolved this issue.

I apologise for any format issues, this is the first time posting on here and also I'm relatively new to using python.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillow 7.0.0 removed PILLOW_VERSION, you should use **version** in your own code instead.

- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html#pillow-version-constant

If using Torchvision, there is a release planned this week (week 2, 2020) to fix it:

- https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1712#issuecomment-570286349

The options are:

- wait for the new torchvision release
- use the master version of torchvision as given below

  ```
  pip install -U git+https://github.com/pytorch/vision)
  ```
- install torchvision from a nightly, which also requires a pytorch from a nightly version
- or install Pillow<7

  ```
  pip install "pillow<7"
  ```